# How can I append features column wise and start a row for each sample

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to create a training data file which is structured as follows:

[Rows = Samples, Columns = features]

So if I have 100 samples and 2 features the shape of my np.array would be (100,2).

The list bellow contains path-strings to the .nrrd 3D sample patch-data files.

```
['/Users/FK/Documents/image/0128/subject1F_200.nrrd',
 '/Users/FK/Documents/image/0128/subject2F_201.nrrd']
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
training_file = []

# For each sample in my image folder
for patches in dir_0128_list:

    # Reads the 64x64x64 numpy array
    data, options = nrrd.read(patches)

    # Calculates the median and sum of the 3D array file. 2 Features per sample
    f_median = np.median(data)
    training_file.append(f_median)

    f_sum = np.sum(data)
    training_file.append(f_sum)


    # Calculates a numpy array with the following shape (169,) containing 169 features per sample.
    f_mof = my_own_function(data)
    training_file.append(f_mof)


training_file = np.array((training_file), dtype=np.float32)    
# training_file = np.column_stack((core_training_list))
```

If I don't use the np.column_stack function I get a (173,1) matrix. (1,173) if I run the function. In this scenario it should have a (2,171) shape.

I want to calculate the sum and median and append it to an list or numpy array column wise. At the end of the for loop I want to jump 1 row down and append the 2 features column wise for the second sample and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Very simple solution

Instead of

```
f_median = np.median(data)
training_file.append(f_median)

f_sum = np.sum(data)
training_file.append(f_sum)
```

you could do do

```
training_file.append((np.median(data), np.sum(data)))
```

## slightly longer solution

Then  you would still have 1 piece of consecutive code that is not easy to reuse and test indicidually.
I would structure the different parts of the script

1. Iterate over the files to read the patches
2. Calculate the mean and sum
3. Aggregate to the requested format

## Read the patches

```
def read_patches(files):
    for file in files:
        yield nrrd.read(file)
```

make a generator yielding the patches info

## Calculate

```
def parse_patch(patch):
    data, options = patch
    return np.median(data), np.sum(data)
```

## Putting it together

```
from pathlib import Path
file_dir = Path(<my_filedir>)
files = file_dir.glob('*.nrrd')

patches = read_patches(files)
training_file = np.array([parse_patch(patch) for patch in patches], dtype=np.float32)
```

This might look convoluted, but it allows for easy testing of each of the sub-blocks

Comment: Is the parameter in the read_patches function supposed to be a directory string? Because I receive the following error: IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/'

Comment: the `files` argument is an iterable of filenames. I added the code to start from a directory

Comment: When I enter the path ('/Users/FK/Documents/image/0128/subject2F_201.nrrd') into  `<my_filedir>` I get the following `TypeError: invalid file: PosixPath`. I have tried navigating inside the directory and use different path listings. I use python 3.5.

Comment: apparently your `pynrrd` can not handle a `Path` object as input. Either add a `files = (str(file) for file in files)` to convert the `Path` objects to string before passing them to `read_patches` or change the last line in `read_patches` to `yield nrrd.read(str(file))`

Comment: Thanks! `yield nrrd.read(str(file))` worked. I will let you know if the approach you have suggested is fully scalable to large samples and features

Comment: I have tried adding my own function to the code. Its output is a (169,) numpy array containing 169 features. When I `return np.median(data), np.sum(data), my_own_function(data)` I get the following `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` the problem lies in the last line in your suggestion.

Comment: the `np.array([parse_patch(patch) for patch in patches], dtype=np.float32)` expects from `parse_patch` a sequence of floats. Your `my_own_function` returns an array, so `parse_patch` return a `tuple(float, float, array)`. You will have to change `parse_patch` so it returns a sequence of floats

Comment: I see, I thought that would be the problem. I have tried running for loop inside parse_patch in order to address each value and then returning the values but it gives me all the wrong results. Would you make changes `[parse_patch(patch) for patch in patches]` ? Is there a more elegant way of converting tuple(float, float, array) to tuple(float, float, float... n= 169)?

Comment: I have tried some other approaches, they didn't really work. I don't really know how to change `parse_patch` it returns a sequence of floats...

Comment: [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to the rescue `return [i for i in itertools.chain((np.median(data), np.sum(data)), my_own_function(data))]`

Comment: Sorry @Maarten I have a follow up question regarding the code above. I was wondering if you could take a look at it. Thank you in advance :) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46007340/how-can-i-append-features-from-two-different-directories-into-a-single-array)