# How can I create single numpy feature array from two arrays and a single float value?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to create a training data file which is structured as follows:

[Rows = Samples, Columns = features]

So if I have 100 samples and 2 features the shape of my np.array would be (100,2) etc.

**Data**

The list bellow contains path-strings to the .nrrd 3D sample patch-data files which have been processed using method 01.

```
['/Users/FK/Documents/image/01/subject1F_200.nrrd',
'/Users/FK/Documents/image/01/subject2F_201.nrrd']
```

Lets call the directory dir_01.
For testing purposes the following 3D patch can be used. It has the same shape as the .nrrd file when read:

```
subject1F_200_PP01 = np.random.rand(128,128, 128)
subject1F_201_PP01 = np.random.rand(128,128, 128)
# and so on...
```

The list bellow contains path-strings to the .nrrd 3D sample patch-data files which have been processed using method 02.

```
['/Users/FK/Documents/image/02/subject1F_200.nrrd',
'/Users/FK/Documents/image/02/subject2F_201.nrrd']
```

Lets call the directory dir_02.
For testing purposes the following 3D patch can be used. It has the same shape as the .nrrd file when read:

```
subject1F_200_PP02 = np.random.rand(128,128, 128)
subject1F_201_PP02 = np.random.rand(128,128, 128)
# and so on...
```

Both the subjects are the same, but the patch data has been pre-processed differently.

**Feature Functions**

In order to calculate the features I need to use the following functions:

1. np.median (regular python function and returns a single value)
2. my_own_function1 (regular python function and returns a np.array)
3. my_own_function2 (I can only access it using a matlab engine and returns a np.array)

In this scenario my final numpy array should have a (2,251) shape. Since I have to samples (rows) and 251 features (columns) from my 3 functions.

**Here is my code (credits to M.Fabré)**

**Read the patches**

```
# Helps me read the files for features 1. and 2. Uses a python .nrrd reader
def read_patches_multi1(files_1):
    for file_1 in files_1:
        yield nrrd.read(str(file_1))

# Helps me read the files for features 3. Uses a matlab .nrrd reader
def read_patches_multi2(files_2):
    for file_2 in files_2:
        yield eng.nrrdread(str(file_2))
```

**Calculate**

```
def parse_patch_multi(patch1, patch2):

    # Structure for python .nrrd reader
    data_1 , option = patch1

    # Structure for matlab .nrrd reader
    data_2 = patch2

    # Uses itertools to combine single float32 value with np.array values
    return [i for i in itertools.chain(np.median(data_1), my_own_function1(data_1), my_own_function2(data_2))]
```

**Execution**

```
# Directories
dir_01 = '/Users/FK/Documents/image/01/'
dir_02 = '/Users/FK/Documents/image/02/'

# Method 01 patch data
file_dir_1 = Path(dir_01)
files_1 = file_dir_1.glob('*.nrrd')
patches_1 = read_patches_multi1(files_1)

# Method 02 patch data
file_dir_2 = Path(dir_02)
files_2 = file_dir_2.glob('*.nrrd')
patches_2 = read_patches_multi2(files_2)

# I think the error lies here...
training_file_multi = np.array([parse_patch_multi(patch1,patch2) for (patch1, patch2) in (patches_1, patches_2)], dtype=np.float32)
```

I have tried multiple approaches but I am keep getting syntax error or the wrong structure. Or the following type error:

```
TypeError: unsupported Python data type: numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: you should provide sample data that can be used to debug the code. You just provided a path to your data, something that offers no help to people who may be able to answer your question. Make some sample data that can be copied and pasted into python.

Comment: The patch data or rather the path contain pre-processed uniform 3D np.arrays of the following shape:  `(128,128,128)`, you can create any random value and the my functions would calculate the relevant features. What I am saying is you can use any uniform 3D numpy array :)

Comment: But thanks for the critique. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but it does not seem too elegant

**I create two funcitons:**

```
def parse_patch_multi1(patch1):

    # Structure for python .nrrd reader
    data_1 , option = patch1

    # Uses itertools to combine single float32 value with np.array values
    return [i for i in itertools.chain(np.median(data_1), 0) my_own_function1(data_1)]


def parse_patch_multi2(patch2):

    # Structure for python .nrrd reader
    data_2 = patch2

    # Uses itertools to combine single float32 value with np.array values
    return [i for i in itertools.chain(my_own_function2(data_2)]
```

**Execution**

```
# Directories
dir_01 = '/Users/FK/Documents/image/01/'
dir_02 = '/Users/FK/Documents/image/02/'

# Method 01 patch data
file_dir_1 = Path(dir_01)
files_1 = file_dir_1.glob('*.nrrd')
patches_1 = read_patches_multi1(files_1)

# Method 02 patch data
file_dir_2 = Path(dir_02)
files_2 = file_dir_2.glob('*.nrrd')
patches_2 = read_patches_multi2(files_2)

training_file_multi1 = np.array([parse_patch_multi1(patch1) for (patch1) in patches_1], dtype=np.float32)
training_file_multi2 = np.array([parse_patch_multi2(patch2) for (patch2) in patches_1], dtype=np.float32)
```

**The trick**

concatenate the two np.arrays along Axis 1

```
training_file_combined= np.concatenate((training_file_multi1, training_file_multi2), axis=1)
```

Shape of the matrix (2,252)